# MixedRadix rounds incorrectly

Tags: date-and-time, units

You can `Round` `Quantity`s.  For example, how many inches are in a meter?

```
UnitConvert[Quantity[1., "Meter"], "Inch"]
(* 39.3701 in *)
```

Let's get rid of those decimals:

```
Round[%]
(* 39 in *)
```

However, we can use `MixedRadix` to generate output more familiar to those of us from the US:

```
UnitConvert[Quantity[1., "Meter"], MixedRadix["Foot", "Inch"]]
(* 3' 3.37008" *)

Round[%]
(* 3' 3" *)
```

### The Problem

How long is it until that sad day when I can no longer use Mathematica?

```
DateDifference[Now, 
 SystemInformation["Kernel", "LicenseExpirationDate"],
 {"Year", "Month", "Week", "Day", "Hour", "Minute", "Second"}
]
(* 4 mo 3 days 1 h 28 min 46.0093 s *)
```

Let's get rid of those decimals again:

```
Round[%]
(* 4 mo 4 days 8 h *)
```

What?

The behavior is somewhat inconsistent; it seems to round to the second unit, unless that unit is `"Days"` *and* is followed by "`Hours`".  Do you think it is a bug?  Has it been fixed in newer versions?

```
SystemInformation["Kernel", "Version"]   === "10.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (September 9, 2014)"
SystemInformation["Kernel", "ReleaseID"] === "10.0.1.0 (5157734, 2014090901)"
```

Comment: I can't find `MixedRadix` in the 10.1 documentation but it works.  How did you find out about this?

Comment: @Edmund I... actually don't remember.  Huh, that's funny, I could have sworn I saw it pop up in one of the examples.

Comment: Not fixed in 10.1 on Windows 8.1 64bit.

Comment: For a workaround use `% /. x_?NumericQ :> Round[x]` instead of `Round[%]`

Comment: @BobHanlon Doesn't work in the edge cases... for example, rounding `Quantity[MixedRadix[1, 11.5], MixedRadix["Feet", "Inches"]]` should round to `2'`, not `1' 12"`.

Comment: @2012rcampion - With v10.1 on my Mac I get `2' 0"`

Comment: @BobHanlon [Not for me...](http://i.imgur.com/7ZWDdzC.png) I guess that's one more thing they fixed in 10.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've passed this report onto the developers responsible, but in the meantime a work-around for this is to specify which unit you're rounding to:

```
In[33]:= DateDifference[Now, 
 SystemInformation["Kernel", "LicenseExpirationDate"], {"Year", 
  "Month", "Week", "Day", "Hour", "Minute", "Second"}]

Out[33]= Quantity[MixedRadix[0, 9, 0, 1, 13, 0, 17.9785], 
 MixedRadix["Years", "Months", "Weeks", "Days", "Hours", "Minutes", 
  "Seconds"]]

In[34]:= Round[%, Quantity[1, "Seconds"]]

Out[34]= Quantity[MixedRadix[0, 9, 0, 1, 13, 0, 18], 
 MixedRadix["Years", "Months", "Weeks", "Days", "Hours", "Minutes", 
  "Seconds"]]
```